# LinkedIn API for Profile fails when querying for courses

Tags: linkedin-api

I recently noticed that my web application was receiving an HTTP 500 from the LinkedIn API for the following call: `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(positions,skills,educations,summary,courses)`

The call worked before and I find no mention of the API changing.

In addition, the call `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(positions,skills,educations,summary)` works just fine. This leads me to suspect a bug when querying for a person's courses.

Both calls are authenticated with OAuth 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happens to me:

this doesn't work for ***some*** people:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,location,industry,summary,positions,picture-url,site-standard-profile-request,api-standard-profile-request,public-profile-url,email-address,languages,skills,certifications,educations,courses)?format=json
```

returns:

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Internal API server error",
  "requestId": "ITDEU5LUHS",
  "status": 500,
  "timestamp": 1455530418689
}
```

this (removing courses) works:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,location,industry,summary,positions,picture-url,site-standard-profile-request,api-standard-profile-request,public-profile-url,email-address,languages,skills,certifications,educations)?format=json
```